# Какую библиотеку использовать для граф.интерфейса на с++?

Tags: c++, gui

Расскажите какие есть библиотеки для создания GUI на c++ и обучающий материал на русском языке для неё.

Comment: Вы хоть ОС укажите, или несколько.

Answer (score 1):

MFC в Visual Studio, Qt, wxWidgets, GTK, FLTK, .........

Вопрос не позволяет дать точный однозначный ответ... :(